# Youtube api - ytplayer is undefined

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

I'm tyring to embed a youtube video using swfobject. I've written a function so that the video plays when a link is clicked. Everything works like a charm in firefox, but in IE6, it says 'ytplayer is undefined' and the video loads, but does not play. Where am I going wrong?
Here's the .js file:

```
var params = { allowScriptAccess: "always" }; 
var atts = { id: "myytplayer" };

swfobject.embedSWF(vidurl, "ytplayer", "470", "350", "8", null, null, params, atts);

function onYouTubePlayerReady(playerId) {    
    ytplayer = document.getElementById("myytplayer");
}

function play() { 
 document.getElementById('videooverlay').style.display="none";
 document.getElementById('playbutton').style.display="none";
 ytplayer.playVideo();
}
```

Comment: You're going wrong in assuming that IE6 works ;) You may want to take a look at Google's Chrome frame for fixing IE problems.http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/

Answer (score 0):

I think your ytplayer.playVideo(); may be getting called before the video loads completely. Try calling play() from within onYouTubePlayerReady().